# Trying to implement a div with scrollbar

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is what I want to do (and it works in Chrome and FF, but not IE8)

[image]

div1 with variable height. 
div2 that is bigger than div1 and should match the div1 height. So, I have enabled scrollbar there.

The content of div2 will be passed by the server(php) inside the page. So, I found the way to set the height with this js code that works on body onload:

```
function onloadfunc()
{
    leftdiv = document.getElementById("leftbottomcontent");
    newsdiv = document.getElementById("latestnewscontent");
    if ( newsdiv != null && leftdiv != null )
    {
        newsdiv.setAttribute('style', 'overflow:auto; height: ' + leftdiv.offsetHeight + 'px;');
    }
}
```

Here is the question, how to enable it in ie8 or maybe there is another way to do the same thing?

Comment: You could try `overflow: scroll`?

Comment: I'd suggest using jQuery, to avoid having to script for multiple browsers.

Comment: @Joshua M - how it will help me to set the right height of the div2?

Answer (score 0):

applying a design to IE is not that easy, I'd recommend you to use an IF statement to determent what browser it is,

You can find a great explantion 
[Over here](http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/)

Comment: Even with IF - I don't know how to do this feature in IE at all.